# Uncaught ReferenceError for a function defined in an onload function

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<div id="myID" onclick="cc(this.id)">Click Here</div>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var timer;
var firing = false;
var begen = function(id) {
    alert('tek');
};

var popupAc = function(id) {
    alert('çift');
};

function cc(id) {
    if (firing) {
        popupAc(id);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        firing = false;
        return;
    }
    firing = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        //begen(id);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        firing = false;
    }, 250);
}
```

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cc is not defined
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LXSZj/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your JSFiddle preferences are set to "onload", so the content of the JavaScript pane is wrapped in a function.

This scopes `cc` (`dd` does not exist, creating an additional problem for the jsfiddle example) to that function and stops it being a global.

Since you are trying to call it from an intrinsic event attribute, you are in a different scope and cannot access it.

As a quick fix, you can change the preference to 'nowrap', however that won't make the code conform to best practises.

It is recommended to avoid intrinsic event attributes in favour of [binding event handlers with Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event#Registering_event_listeners). YUI3 provides an [event module](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/) and jQuery provides the [`on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to help with this (other libraries are available). See also: [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

For example, [see this js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LXSZj/9/).

Comment: Great explanation so I want to accept this answer, could you add jsfiddle link. I have answer. But if you add it will be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

It does, you just have two errors in your fiddle:

- You called `dd` instead of `cc`
- You wrapped your whole javascript in a onload-function (see dropdown on the left), and the variables and functions are local to that. Move it to the global scope, or assign the `cc` function to the global object: `window.cc = function(){…};`

[Corrected version](http://jsfiddle.net/LXSZj/5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.cc = function(id) { ...
```

the variables and functions seem to be in their on scope...