# jsFiddle not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, jsfiddle

Recently I created a fiddle with the following code -

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="action();">click me<img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1" width="200px" id="ImageButton1"></button>
```

**JS**

```
function action ( )
{

if(document.getElementById("#ImageButton1").src == 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1' )
document.getElementById("#ImageButton1").src = 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/dec4ce/fff.gif&text=Image+2';
else
document.getElementById("#ImageButton1").src = 'http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000000/fff.gif&text=Image+1';
}
```

**Fiddle Link** - http://jsfiddle.net/QVRUG/4/

This code is working in `FF` and in my local `html` file but throws error in `chrome` console -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: action is not defined
```

I further investigated the error and found -

[Uncaught ReferenceError for a function defined in an onload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318089/uncaught-referenceerror-for-a-function-defined-in-an-onload-function)

So I tried this also -

```
window.action = function(){...code here...};
```

But no luck :(

Kindly let me know about this behavior why it is not working in chrome and working for others. Please don't just provide a patch to make the fiddle working as I am also interested about the behavior. Descriptive answers(with relevant link for further study) really appreciated in the case so that I can move properly in my rest of projects.

Let me know if the question is not on the track, I will take it down(although I put my honest efforts to make the question clean and clear)

Comment: Frameworks & Extensions = jQuery 1.7.2

Comment: @SameerH.Ibra I know I can manage it from jQuery but I am looking for JS this time ONLY..haven't tagged it with jQuery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the "language" is set as `Javascript 1.7` in your jsFiddle.

**Why does this only work in Firefox?**

[**According to the versioning history**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history), `1.7` was only ever supported in the Mozilla Firefox browser, hence why it works there and not in other browsers.

**Solution:**

Change the language from `Javascript 1.7` to `Javascript` in the **Languages** section of your jsFiddle and it will work. I'm guessing you must have changed it to 1.7 specifically, because the default is normally just `Javascript` (you can see that by pasting your code into a new jsFiddle, where it will work as expected).

[***jsFiddle example.***](http://jsfiddle.net/QVRUG/36/)

Comment: thx for the answer, I think unintentionally I changed it ..so I believe thr is no MAGIC else in the code that I need to know?

Comment: @swapnesh Check this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Version_history - 1.7 was only ever supported in Mozilla, hence why it works in Firefox and not other browsers.

Comment: oh wow..thx for the info..i will keep the things in mind now :)